# Replace selected code from Eclipse editor plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i'm trying to create an Eclipse Plug-In, activable with a menu button, that pass the selected text, and i take it like this:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        IEditorPart editor = window.getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
        ITextSelection selection = (ITextSelection) editor.getEditorSite().getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        String selectedText = selection.getText();
```

Now I do stuff and process user selected text.

How i can do for replace the selectedText?

Comment: The Find/Replace dialog uses the `IFindReplaceTarget` interface, but I don't know any details.